# On Select change show div content according to value FormArray Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7, formarray

I am developing a form in Angular 7, I am using `Reactive Form` which has `FormArray` in it.

There are `<select></select>` control in each FormArray

This is Form Structure

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      'listid': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'segmentName': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'description': ['', [Validators.required]],
      listFieldArray: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
```

And this is FormArray Structure

```
addListFieldsFormGroup(name: string, value: string): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'condition': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'name': [name],
      'value': [value, [Validators.required]],
      'type': ['1', [Validators.required]],
      'operator': ['', [Validators.required]],
      'operand': ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
  }
```

`condition` in FormArray is a Select Control, on chage of this select, I want to show Div according to value

```
<div class="clr-row">
          <clr-select-container>
            <select clrSelect formControlName="sentCondition">
              <option value="">Select </option>
              <option value="custom">Custom</option>
              <option value="between">Between</option>
              <option value="lessThenEqual">Less then or Equal</option>
              <option value="moreThen">More then</option>
            </select>
          </clr-select-container>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-row" *ngIf="sentCondition==='custom'">
          <div class="clr-col-4 ">
            <input clrInput placeholder="From Day" type="date" formControlName="customDayFrom" />
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col-4 ">
            <input clrInput placeholder="To Day" type="date" formControlName="customDayTo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-row" *ngIf="sentCondition==='between'">
          <div class="clr-col-4 ">
            <input clrInput placeholder="From Day" formControlName="customDayFrom" />
          </div>
          <div class="clr-col-4 ">
            <input clrInput placeholder="To Day" formControlName="customDayTo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clr-row" *ngIf="sentCondition==='lessThenEqual' || sentCondition==='moreThen'">
          <div class="clr-col-4 ">
            <input clrInput placeholder="Day" formControlName="customDayFrom" />
          </div>
        </div>
```

It was working with `[(ngModel)]` but now it is deprecated in Angular 7 with Reactive Form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hash on select something like

```
 <select clrSelect formControlName="sentCondition" #someHashName>
```

then on div use `if condition` something like

```
<div *ngIf="someHashName?.value == 'yourcondition'">
```